# Help on : silverlight 4 and livestreams from tv tuner card

Tags: silverlight, mediaelement

Is it possible to get livetv streams from tvtuner cards ( Elgato , hauppauge ) to silverlights mediaelement or other ( WPF ). and control channel shifting ? Perhaps through vlc ?.

Need it for a demo app. So the solution do not need to be pretty :). Hope its possible
Any thoughts ?

cheers
/Bo

Comment: I am also looking for this, do you find one?

Comment: Nope not yet unfortunately , if I do I will post it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You might try looking at Vlc.DotNet.Wpf. Which is available on Codeplex. It provides wpf support for VLC.

Hope that helps!